# How to access a foreign key related field in a template when using Django model form

Tags: python, django

***My Objective***

Access the field `name` in the Parent Model `ParentModel` and display its content in a `form instance` in the template. For example, let the field `parent` be a `foreign key` in the `ChildModel` as described below.

**What I have tried**

Access the parent field in the form as `{{ form.parent.name }}` in the template

***Errors received***

```
Tried looking up form.parent.name in context
```

***models.py***

```py
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.parent.name
```

***forms.py***

```
class ChildModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'parent': forms.Select(),}
```

***views.py***

```
def childView(request, pk):
    template = 'template.html'
    child = ChildModel.objects.get(parent=pk)
    form = ChildModelForm(instance=child)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChildModelForm(request.POST, instance=child)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form = ChildModelForm(instance=child)
    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**template.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.parent.name}}
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now the child model form displays `pk` I want to display the name of the parent field

I have also tried using this [Django access foreignkey fields in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192329/django-access-foreignkey-fields-in-a-form) but it did not work for me.

Comment: define a `__str__` method in your parent model and return `self.name`. Then the name is going to be shown in the form

Comment: @Wariored I have added the methods to both models, doing this is only applicable when displaying the content of a model in a template eg ```{{x.parent.name}}```. What I need is displaying an instance of a form ie ```{{form.parent.name}}```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to display the form instance's values. You can do:

```
form.instance.parent.name
```